How to change the template (icon, item, shortcut key) of menuitem to your own?
I'm trying to change the template to display items in menuitem. But even when I made the template and style empty, wpf keeps outputting information like: icon, item, shortcut key. And I noticed that it takes this template from standard windows templates (ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey). If you add it to XALM and change it, the output will change too. However, I don't see a way to apply my own template. It turns out I can change the output only for all menuitem that I have.
My code:
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemp" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="item" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyTemp}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <MenuItem Name="menu" Header="New" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
        <CheckBox Content="source"/>
        <CheckBox Content="source 2"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Grid>

I tried changing the menuitem template (code above). But it only changes the shell output of the template. I tried to apply the template to the item. This code:
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="myText"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

But this only changes the item template, and the icon and key space remain.
P.S. I know I can hide this space with margin, however windows will draw extra elements and leave more than necessary space for menuitem.
